# Does Apache2 support virtual hosting of subdomains?

Tags: apache2, subdomain, virtualhost

Currently my Apache server is set up like so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.example.com
 ServerAlias example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that everything below `/var/www` is accessible from everywhere else. If I have a web page `/var/www/john/bio.html`, then that web page could borrow scripts/pictures from `var/www/jane/`

I want to set up my Apache server like so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.example.com
 ServerAlias example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.john.example.com
 ServerAlias john.example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/john
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.jane.example.com
 ServerAlias jane.example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/jane
</VirtualHost>
```

So all the files for user `john` go in the `/var/www/john/` folder, and likewise for user `jane`. Then, with symbolic links turned off (by default), and access only provided from `/var/www/user/` downwards (again by default), I don't have to worry about `john's` web page including scripts/images from `jane's` web page.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using local measures only (`/etc/hosts` instead of a DNS) I found that this can indeed work.

First, change your `/etc/hosts` file to have a mapping of your desired website name(s) ([www.example.com](http://www.google.com)), and target IP address (192.168.1.1). I used my local IP address.

```
 IPAddress               Hostname                   Alias
-----------     --------------------------    ------------------
192.168.1.1     www.example.com               example.com 
192.168.1.1     www.john.example.com          john.example.com
192.168.1.1     www.jane.example.com          jane.example.com
```

Your web browser will check your `/etc/hosts` file **before** looking at the world wide web.

Next go through all your Apache config files (`httpd.conf`, `apache2.conf`, `ports.conf`, `conf.d/*`) and make sure in **exactly one** file the command `NameVirtualHost *:80` is issued (it doesn't have to be port `:80` but if it is issued more than once, you will get [this problem](https://serverfault.com/q/1405/99913)). Mine was issued in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, so put yours there if you have to. Finally, update your Apache configuration file (mine was at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`) like so.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.john.example.com
    ServerAlias john.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/john
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.jane.example.com
    ServerAlias jane.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/jane
</VirtualHost>
```

As a final step, you may need to add the websites to Apache by issuing the below commands (this step is not necessary, if you give all websites into `sites-available/default` and not into separate files for individual websites).

```
# a2ensite www.example.com
# a2ensite www.john.example.com
# a2ensite www.jane.example.com
```

After doing this, `john.example.com` will go to `/var/www/john`. That directory will then act as the root directory, and `john` will no longer have access to `www`, and, therefore, have no access to `/var/www/jane`.

Likewise, after doing this, `jane.example.com` will go to `/var/www/jane`. That directory will then act as the root directory, and `jane` will no longer have access to `www`, and, therefore, have no access to `/var/www/john`.

With symbolic links turned off --by default-- neither directories will be able to access each other

Comment: This helped me remember that I forgot to change my hosts file. Thanks man from the past.

Comment: @MeowMix glad I could help at least one person

Comment: Command `a2ensite example.com` create symlink from `sites-available/example.com` to `sites-enabled/example.com`, opposite command is `a2dissite example.com`, which would disable it.