# How to configure a subdomain in Amazon AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I am trying to configure a subdomain in AWS, but its not working when I configure it as follows:

```
subdomain.domain.com

type: CNAME

TTL: 60

value domain.com/page.php
```

So I was thinking of an alternative solution. Since linking to an `ip address` to a website, if there was a way i could grab the ip address of that `domain.com/page.php`, but I am not sure if that's even possible.

Comment: DNS and the web simply do not work this way.  You can't magically map a hostname to a different host *and path*.  It might help if you explain what you are actually trying to accomplish, and why, rather than the particular approach you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

What you need would be better accomplished via a .htaccess file placed at the root of `subdomain.domain.com`. `.htaccess`'s scope will be to define rules that will instruct the web server to redirect requests from your subdomain to a new URL.

See [htaccess redirect subdomain to root domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637933/htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-root-domain) for a possible implementation of `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

You would like subdomain.domain.com to work using Amazon's Route53?
Are you using Apache on a linux server?  Are you using a IIS Windows server?

I'll give you the directions for Apache.  You need a new name-based virtual host.
Add the following to your Apache Config file.  (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/test.mydomain.com/"
    ServerName test.mydomain.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then login to AWS Route 53 and setup an **A record.**

```
A Record -> IP Based -> 123.123.123.123(the IP of your Apache server)
```

[Does Apache2 support virtual hosting of subdomains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044221/does-apache2-support-virtual-hosting-of-subdomains)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html